# How do I get the date of each category state change on a work item in Azure DevOps Boards?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

The category states are **Proposed**, **In Progress**, **Resolved**, **Completed**, and **Removed** as defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/workflow-and-state-categories?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#category-states), and these apply to all ADO processes.

Side Note: Ideally, I would be able to query the **state category** of a work item, but there is not a system field that contains that.

| State Category | Date Field |
| --- | --- |
| Proposed | Created Date |
| In Progress | Activated Date |
| Resolved | Resolved Date |
| Completed | ***??? Date*** |
| Removed | ***??? Date*** |

I reviewed the documentation and only found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/workflow-and-state-categories?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#activated-bydate-and-resolved-bydate-fields), which covers Activated Date and Resolved Date fields.
I called the [Work Item Types Field - List REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-item-types-field/list) and reviewed all fields with Date in the name and referenced their docs. Edit: I also reviewed all fields with referenceName starting with "System." just in case it didn't have Date in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like at least some the fields you're looking for start with `Microsoft.VSTS.Common` instead of `System`, for whatever reason.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-workflow-changes?view=azure-devops#workflow-and-kanban-board-fields, four out of the five are pretty simple:

| State Category | Date Field | Reference Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Proposed | Created Date | `System.CreatedDate` |
| In Progress | Activated Date | `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate` |
| Resolved | Resolved Date | `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate` |
| Completed | Closed Date | `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate` |
| Removed | ***??? Date*** |  |

For the removed state, while there's no "removed date" that I could find, a combination of filtering on  `System.State` = 'Removed' and checking those tasks' `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate` should get you some of the information you need, but would miss out on any tasks that had been un-removed.

If that isn't enough, I think you could use a hacky workaround:

1. Create a new date field called "Removed Date" or something similar (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops)
2. Create a new workflow rule (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) so that whenever an item changes to the state "Removed" (or any other states in your removed category), you use the current time to set "Removed Date" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/rule-reference?view=azure-devops&tabs=inheritance#ip-rule-composition)
3. Query based on your custom field (reference name should be `Custom.RemovedDate` or similar, based on the name chosen in 1. with spaces removed)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to improve the formatting. As is, the table is malformed and difficult to read.

Comment: Ace, thanks for your investigation. Is ClosedDate automatically updated for all states in the Completed category? I could not find this specified in the docs. Also, I think that your workarounds regarding the Removed State Category are creative and may work for someone else, but I am looking for a solution that works with all (custom) processes. E.G., there may be multiple states that map to the Removed category (and I don't want to have to change my process if someone adds a state). I'm hoping that ADO has some design consistency that I am just missing, but it doesn't look like it so far.

Comment: Unfortunately, I made an assumption with ClosedDate, and I don't actually have the rights to test in on my instance of ADO. It would make sense, but I can't guarantee that it does. (as far as ADO design consistency... well......)